# Python struct.calcsize length

Tags: python

```
>>>import struct
>>>size_a = struct.calcsize('10s')
size_a = 10
>>>size_b = struct.calcsize('iii')
size_b = 12
>>>size_c = struct.calcsize('10siii')
size_c = 24
```

Could someone tell me why size_c is `24` rather than `22`(10 + 12) ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has to do with [alignment](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct-alignment). Any particular type (byte, integer,
etc.) can only begin at an offset that is a multiple of its standard size.

- A byte string `s` can begin at any offset because its standard size is 1.
- But a 32-bit integer `i` can only begin at an offset with a multiple of 4
  (its size). E.g., 0, 4, 8, 12, etc.

So, to analyze the struct `10siii` let's first dissect the 10 byte string.

```
Offset: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        s----------------->
```

`10s` takes up the first 10 bytes which is to be expected. Now the
following 3 integers.

```
                            1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
Offset: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
        s-----------------> x x i-----> i-----> i----->
```

Each integer spans 4 bytes, but each can only begin at an offset that's a
multiple of 4 (i.e., 8, 12, 16, 20, not 10). Since the beginning byte string occupies 10 bytes, it has to be
padded by 2 bytes to allow the integers to be at a proper offset. And thus you end up with a total struct size consisting of: 10 (beginning byte string) + 2 (padding) + 12 (3 integers) = 24 byte struct.